# Spivak Calculus Logarithms

Tags: calculus, analysis, logarithms

In Spivak's calculus book, when introducing logarithms, he says that we seek to find a function $f$ such that:

$f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$, for all $x, y$.

He then says, the condition $f(1) = 10$ implies from the previous equation that $f(x) = 10^x$ for rational $x$.

Could someone please explain how?

Thanks!

Comment: Which part are you confused with? The part where the author says f=10^x? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how he gets to f = 10^x.

Comment: Start by proving that $f(nx)=(f(x))^n$ for integers $n$. Then extend to rationals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will show that $f(x)=10^x$ first for $x\in\mathbb N$, then we will expand to $x\in\mathbb Z$ and, finally, to $x\in\mathbb Q$.

### Case $x\in\mathbb N$

First, let's find $f(0)$. Note that $10=f(1)=f(1+0)=f(1)f(0)=10f(0)$. By canceling $10$ on both sides, we conclude that $f(0)=1$.

Next, let's prove that, for $n\in\mathbb N$, $f(nx)=f(x)^n$. This goes by induction:

- $n=0$: true as we have just proved that $f(0)=1=f(x)^0$
- $n\to n+1$: $f((n+1)x)=f(nx)\cdot f(x)=f(x)^n\cdot f(x)=f(x)^{n+1}$

From this, putting $x=1$ we see that $f(n)=f(1)^n=10^n$.

### Case $x\in\mathbb Z$

Next, let's assume $n\in\mathbb Z$: $1=f(0)=f(n+(-n))=f(n)\cdot f(-n)$, so $f(-n)=\frac{1}{f(n)}$. In particular, as we know $f(n)=10^n$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, then $f(-n)=\frac{1}{10^n}=10^{-n}$.

### Case $x\in\mathbb Q$

Finally, let's take $x\in\mathbb Q$. Say $x=p/q$ with $p\in\mathbb Z, q\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$. We have already proven that $f(qx)=f(x)^q$. However, this means that $10^p=f(p)=f(qx)=f(x)^q$, so $f(x)=(10^p)^{1/q}=10^{p/q}=10^x$

Thus, the formula $f(x)=10^x$ is valid for each $x\in\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 3):

For any integer $n$, we have $(f(1/n))^n = f(1) = 10$, so $f(1/n) = 10^{1/n}$.

Now for any integer $m$, we have $f(m/n) = (f(1/n))^m = (10^{1/n})^m = 10^{m/n}$.

So the equation holds for all rationals, as required.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=f(x/2 + x/2) = f(x)^2 \geqslant 0$ and if $f(x)=0$ then $\forall y,f(y)=0$ and this is not possible since $f(1)=10\neq 0$ So $g:x\mapsto \ln f(x)$ is well defined.

Then $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$ for all $x,y$.

We easily get $g(n) = n g(1)$ by induction for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, and then for $\mathbb{Z}$.

If $r=p/q$ is rational then $g(p)=g(qr)=qg(r)$ so $g(r)=p/q$.

So for all rational $x$, $g(x)=x g(1)$.

So for all rational $x$, $f(x) = \exp (g(x)) = e^{g(1)x}$.

The condition $f(1) = 10$ implies $g(1)=\ln 10$ so $$\forall x, f(x) = e^{\ln 10 x}=10^x$$